# code should not return any node object(Element)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, linked-list, stack

https://gist.github.com/manaidu-2002/3f7eb60b8521201eba6548ca23cec053

Code returning Node Object(Element), please check the test cases and help me with this

"""Add a couple methods to our LinkedList class,
and use that to implement a Stack.
You have 4 functions below to fill in:
insert_first, delete_first, push, and pop.
Think about this while you're implementing:
why is it easier to add an "insert_first"
function than just use "append"?"""

```py
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def insert_first(self, new_element):
        "Insert new element as the head of the LinkedList"
        new_element.next = self.head
        self.head = e_insert
        

    def delete_first(self):
        "Delete the first (head) element in the LinkedList as return it"
        temp = self.head
        if temp == None:
            return None
        s= temp
        self.head = temp.next
        return s

class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self,head=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(head)

    def push(self, new_element):
        "Push (add) a new element onto the top of the stack"
        temp = self.ll.head
        while temp.next :
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = new_element
            

    def pop(self):
        "Pop (remove) the first element off the top of the stack and return it"
        
        
         if self.ll.head.next == None :
            temp = self.ll.head
            e= temp
            temp = None
            return e
        elif self.ll.head.next:
            temp = self.ll.head
            while temp.next.next:
                   temp = temp.next
            e= temp.next
            temp.next = None
            return e
        return None
    
# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a Stack
stack = Stack(e1)

# Test stack functionality
stack.push(e2)
stack.push(e3)
print(stack.pop().value)
print(stack.pop().value)
print(stack.pop().value)
print(stack.pop())
stack.push(e4)
print(stack.pop().value)
```

Comment: What is `e_insert`? It is nowhere defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is an unused name reference in your code: `e_insert`. This should read `new_element`.

The main issue is that your `Stack` class is not re-using the code you already have in your `LinkedList` class. In the new code you have written there are several mistakes in how you deal with `next`, but taking a step back, you are making a critical mistake in thinking that the top of the stack should be at the **tail** of the linked list, but that is very inefficient. The top of the stack should be at the **head** of the linked list. It is at that side that you can easily remove and insert elements without having to iterate the list.

So take these points into consideration:

- Reuse the code you already have for `LinkedList`. In other words, call the *methods* defined on the `LinkedList` class.
- The top of the stack is at the head of the linked list.

That means the `Stack` class can be as simple as this:

```
class Stack(LinkedList):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(head)

    def push(self, new_element):
        self.ll.insert_first(new_element)
            
    def pop(self):
        return self.ll.delete_first()
```

Comment: You have told about mistakes dealing with next can you elaborate it

Comment: Can you elaborate about my mistakes with using next ?

Comment: There are several. I stopped looking further, because the approach to iterate the list was a bad decision anyway. But for instance, `if self.ll.head.next == None`  is wrong. It should be `if self.ll.head == None`. But that is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: if self.ll.head.next == None
Then only I can use while loop and be able to remove the last element as I need to stop before the second last element and change its reference

Comment: The point is that `self.ll.head` can be `None` and `self.ll.head.next` will lead to an exception then.

Comment: Ok, thanks by the way. I am a new user on this platform.